# Embedded ApacheDS 2.0.0-M16 (on 2nd run only): ERR_250_ENTRY_ALREADY_EXISTS ou=system already exists

Tags: ldap, apacheds

Using [this example](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12626473/EmbeddedADSVerTrunkV2.java) as base, my embedded ApacheDS server runs fine the first time, then, when I stop the JBoss server on which my app runs and start again, and re-deploy, the log returns a load of errors starting with:

'(ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapEntryAlreadyExistsException: ERR_250_ENTRY_ALREADY_EXISTS ou=system already exists!)'

followed by others that have been accurately identified in this Apache [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER-1954)

Every time I stop and start JBoss thereafter, the ApacheDS server starts just fine (same as in the JIRA issue)

The JIRA page states that the issue has been fixed with a little workaround, which I have applied

```
public EmbeddedADSVerTrunkV2(final File workDir) throws Exception
{
    if (!workDir.exists())
    {
        workDir.mkdirs();
        this.initDirectoryService(workDir);
        this.service.shutdown();
    }

    this.initDirectoryService(workDir);
}
```

but the problem remains for me. The second run always fails before succeeding on the third and subsequent runs.

Are there any new workarounds or fixes that I have missed? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was already fixed, please verify if you have the correct version of the jar file(s).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding :) I have whatever jar files are downloaded from the Maven repository with the following dependencies specified in the pom: `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-M16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>`